# dial tcp i/o timeout then logging in to minio

Tags: docker, timeout, minio

I've setup an minio installation via docker on one of my servers.
I can access the login screen without a problem. However, when the login itself does not work.

> Post "https://example.com:9000/": dial tcp :9000: i/o timeout

**What could be the reason for this?**

This is my docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-05-19T18-20-59Z.fips
    command: server -C /etc/minio --address ":9000" --console-address ":9001" /data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_SERVER_URL: "https://example.com:9000"
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: "minioadmin"
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: "minioadmin"
    volumes:
      - minio:/data
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/
      - /etc/minio:/etc/minio/
      
volumes:
  minio:
```

there is also an nginx running on that server but I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I was using Traefik as a reverse proxy.

To fix it, MINIO_SERVER_URL had to be accessible internally using the name of the service in docker-compose otherwise minio-console cant resolve the server through Traefik.

Try setting it like this in docker-compose without https and with the service name and port:

MINIO_SERVER_URL: "http://minio:9000"

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error since I've added `MINIO_SERVER_URL`.

But I read that is the way we can get correct share links.

I hope someone else can have good ideas on how to solve that.

Edit:
Found a similar issue https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/13859

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case Minio is installed on a Synology NAS, and I use a Reverse Proxy to use my Synology subdomain (full details on the specific setup, including domain used and reverse proxy at this [link](https://randomds.com/2023/01/06/deploy-minio-with-docker-on-a-synology-nas-with-a-custom-domain-name/))

I managed to have a working installation by using the following Docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9777:9777"
      - "9701:9701"
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/minio/data:/data
      - /volume1/docker/minio/config:/root/.minio
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: YourOwnUser
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: YourOwnPasswd
      MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL: "https://mc.yoursub.synology.me"
      #MINIO_SERVER_URL: "https://minio.yoursub.synology.me"
      MINIO_API_DISABLE_ODIRECT: "on"
    command: server --address ":9777" --console-address ":9701" /data
```

I had to comment out the environment variable `MINIO_SERVER_URL`, and only use the `MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL` one with the URL for Minio Console (which is the one you use when you login from the browser...the other one is for the API). It mostly works, but I cannot manage to display the files from the Object Browser. The Python client works seamlessly from the Internet and the local network. Hope it helps!